# PayPal Laravel 6 integration using srmklive error

Tags: laravel, paypal

I am facing an issue in srmklive/paypal integration in Laravel 6.I have published all services also cleared cache and config but still error is coming.

> Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout' not found

The code of my paypal payment controller is below

```php
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\Paypal;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;

class PayPalController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Responds with a welcome message with instructions
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function payment()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['items'] = [
            [
                'name' => 'ItSolutionStuff.com',
                'price' => 100,
                'desc'  => 'Description for ItSolutionStuff.com',
                'qty' => 1
            ]
        ];
  
        $data['invoice_id'] = 1;
        $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$data['invoice_id']} Invoice";
        $data['return_url'] = route('payment.success');
        $data['cancel_url'] = route('payment.cancel');
        $data['total'] = 100;
  
        $provider = new ExpressCheckout;
  
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
  
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);
  
        return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
    }
   
    /**
     * Responds with a welcome message with instructions
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check following steps in your application and apply it.

1 . Please Install Laravel Package for PayPal Library.

```
composer require srmklive/paypal
```

2.You can update your `app.php` file for provider. Look Like

```
   'providers' => [
      Srmklive\PayPal\Providers\PayPalServiceProvider::class
    ]
```

3.Now you an run following command in terminal.

```
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider "Srmklive\PayPal\Providers\PayPalServiceProvider"`
```

4.You can update your `paypal.php` file inside config folder.

5.You can run following command then it will be work perfectly.

`php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache`

I hope It will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response...i have tried this solution but still same issue

Comment: Ok Please check your vendor folder inside directory `Srmklive`.

Comment: You can change your namespace Look Like : `use Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\Paypal;`. It should be `use Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\PayPal;`

Comment: i have changed it but still issue is not fixed

Comment: @AsadMalik Please check vendor folder `vendor/srmklive/paypal/src/Services/ExpressCheckout.php` file is exit or not. If not then Issue with composer install.